# SQLAlchemy pool

Tags: python

Пробую использовать `SQLAlchemy` с `pool`, выполняю код:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/DB', pool_size=10,max_overflow=5)
dbHandle = engine.connect()
```

Я как понимаю, если использовать `pool_size`, то соединений должно быть 10, если посмотреть `mysql.log`, например:

```
            26731 Connect   root@localhost on DB
            26732 Connect   root@localhost on DB
            26733 Connect   root@localhost on DB
            26734 Connect   root@localhost on DB
            26735 Connect   root@localhost on DB
            26736 Connect   root@localhost on DB
            26737 Connect   root@localhost on DB
            26738 Connect   root@localhost on DB
            26739 Connect   root@localhost on DB
            26740 Connect   root@localhost on DB
```

Или я ошибаюсь? Если я ошибаюсь, поясните, как тогда работает `pool` в `SQLAlchemy`.

Answer (score 1):

Из документации по соответствующему `QueuePool`:

> **pool_size** – The size of the pool to be maintained, defaults to 5. This is the largest number of connections that will be kept persistently in the pool. Note that the pool begins with no connections; once this number of connections is requested, that number of connections will remain. pool_size can be set to 0 to indicate no size limit; to disable pooling, use a NullPool instead.

Таким образом, набор соединений будет расти до `pool_size` и останется постоянным в случае достижения этого числа.